# for loop/print or println formatting issue

Tags: java

I am suppose to read in a text document (I/O) and display the number and the number of asterisks as the number. So *"5 1 3"* would display as:

> 5*****
>
> 1*
>
> 3***

My code displays the output as *"5*****1*3***"*. I have tried a number of things but cannot figure it out.

My code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HWK1B {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("data.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            int num;
            num = inFile.nextInt();
            System.out.print(num);
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: the answer is in the question title.

Comment: this worked thank you very much! however my online system wont recognize it as correct because it wants the numbers to be in order. so if the same numbers used are 5,1,2,3,4,5, it wants the answers formatted like 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Then you have to first read the content, sort it, and then print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `System.out.println()` at the end of your main loop and it will go the next line.

```
while(inFile.hasNext())
{
    int num; 
    num = inFile.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print(num);
    for(int i=0; i < num; i++) 
    { 
        System.out.print("*"); 
    } 
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start a new line, you need a "newline character" so that the display knows to separate the lines. One way is to manually add a newline character, which is denoted by "\n".

The second way is to generate your string all at once (so you build the string "5*****" instead of printing it one character at a time), and then printing it using the "println" (or print line) command.

The first way is a bit more efficient as well as easier to work into your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You never do a linebreak, so the console prints it out all in a row.

To insert a linebreak you can use e.g. the `System.out.println()` method.
This code should give you 2 linebreaks after each number:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("data.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
        while(inFile.hasNext()) {
            int num;
            num = inFile.nextInt();
            System.out.print(num);
            for(int i=0; i < num; i++) {
               System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this is by simply adding `System.out.println()` (or two by the look of your example) after you added the astericks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HWK1B
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
       File file = new File("data.txt"); 
       Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file); 
       while(inFile.hasNext())
       {
          int num; 
          num = inFile.nextInt(); 
          System.out.print(num);
          for(int i=0; i < num; i++) 
          { 
             System.out.print("*"); 
          } 
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
       }
       inFile.close(); 
    }
}
```

If you changed `System.out.print(num)` to `System.out.println(num)`, a new line would be added before the asterisks resulting in an example such as:

```
5
*****1
*3***
```

If you changed `System.out.print("*")` to `System.out.println("*")`, a new line would be added every time an asterick is added resulting in:

```
5*
*
*
*
*
1*3*
*
*
```